# Why can't I see Ads in my Android app? (getting Invalid response code:499)

Tags: android, admob

I can't see Ads in my app, using Google Admob.

This is the `LogCat` output:

```
01-22 02:11:21.335: I/Ads(626): Request scenario: Online server request. 
01-22 02:11:21.666: I/Ads(626): Invalid response code: 499 
01-22 02:11:21.666: D/webviewglue(626): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a206860 
01-22 02:11:21.675: I/Ads(626): onFailedToReceiveAd(There was an internal 
error.)
```

What I can do for fix this?

```
private AdView adMobView;
    private AdRequest adMobRequest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ....
           startAds();
           .....
         }


       private void startAds () {

       //AdMob
           adMobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_ID);
           LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
           layout.addView(adMobView);
           adMobRequest = new AdRequest();
           adMobView.loadAd(adMobRequest);
    }
```

MANIFEST XML

```
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
...
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"           
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
        ..
```

I have testing on device Galaxy S4 and on Android simulated device.

Today on AdMob stats I have totalized 33 request 0 impression, but yesterday i have totalized 77 request and only 1 impression. I don't know if the problem is in my code or Google don't send me an ads.

However if i set test mode on true, I receive the same error that i paste on top :(

Comment: You should probably include the relevant source code and describe you attempts so that it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: private AdView adMobView; 
    private AdRequest adMobRequest;
    
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
                    (...)
                    startads();
    
            }
     private void startAds () {
      
        //AdMob
            adMobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_ID);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            layout.addView(adMobView);
            adMobRequest = new AdRequest();
            adMobView.loadAd(adMobRequest);
     }

Comment: Great. Now, you can edit your question to include it. Try to format it properly (take a look at the way I edited your original post).

Comment: XML MANIFEST:

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"           
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
        

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: What version of Admob or Google play Services are you using?

Comment: The last version: 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdView adMobView; 
private AdRequest adMobRequest;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                (...)
                startads();

        }
    private void startAds () {

       //AdMob
           adMobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_ID);
           LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
           layout.addView(adMobView);
           adMobRequest = new AdRequest();
           adMobView.loadAd(adMobRequest);
    }
```

XML MANIFEST:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"           
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Nothing?